# Not fire button event after attribut adding window open, how to trigger both?

Tags: asp.net, .net

```
button1.attributes.add("onclick", "window.open(....)")
```

`button_click(object sender, eventargs e)` not run

How to make button click trigger when opening a new window?

Comment: Do you mean "ASP.NET"? (ASP is pre-.NET)

Comment: Please revise your question: what are you trying to do, as things stand this will be closed as not-understandable. PS. I think you are confusing client and server side code.

Answer (score 0):

call like this...dont call the `window.open` directly

```
button1.attributes.add("onclick", "openwindow()")

function openwindow() {
   window.open(....);
}
```